# Displaying an Intellisense-like window while typing (can't get the coords right)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to display a small intellisense-like window (it's a small Form), right below the last character of the text but with my current code its coordinates seem random and not very accurate. Any help would be appreaciated.

When I press Alt+1 (to display the intelliense-like window while typing, I call this code:

```
shortcuts.Location = GetPoint((TextBox)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]);
shortcuts.Show(this);
```

And the coed that gets the coordinates is:

```
private Point GetPoint(TextBox textBoxControl)
        {
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(textBoxControl.Handle);
            SizeF size = graphics.MeasureString(textBoxControl.Text.Substring(0,
                         textBoxControl.SelectionStart), textBoxControl.Font);
            Point coord = new Point((int)size.Width + textBoxControl.Location.X,
                          (int)size.Height + 200 + textBoxControl.Location.Y);
            return coord;
        }
```

---

## Working code

I'll admit there's probably a better way of doing this but this is working perfectly for me:

```
private Point GetPoint(TextBox textBoxControl)
{
    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(textBoxControl.Handle);
    SizeF size = graphics.MeasureString(textBoxControl.Text.Substring(0,
                 textBoxControl.SelectionStart), textBoxControl.Font);
    Point coord = new Point(this.Left + (int)size.Width + textBoxControl.Location.X + 5,
                  this.Location.Y + 25 + toolStrip1.Height + tabControl1.Top + (int)size.Height + tabControl1.Top + textBoxControl.Location.Y + 25);
    return coord;
}
```

However, for some reason, the very first time this method gets called, it always just appears at some random location - though every subsequent call to this method results in the window being placed where it should; just below the current line of text and horizontally aligned so that the window is right after the last character in the textbox.

Comment: How much variance is there?  Off by a character, or off by half the form?

Comment: @DonBoitnott it's off by about half the width of the form.

Comment: Maybe you should use textBoxControl.PointToScreen as the offset-base.

Comment: I"ll have to lookup PointToScreen as I'm not familiar with it - thanks fo the tip! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
TextBox tb = (TextBox)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0];
Point thePoint = GetPoint(tb);
shortcuts.Location = tb.PointToClient(tabControl1.PointToScreen(thePoint));  //assuming "this" is the form itself
```

In the GetPoint() method, replace "200 + " with tabControl1.GetTabRect(0).Height.  I also had to add 5 as padding to both X and Y because the tabControl has some spacing.

Comment: @Jase Sorry, I forgot to account for the TabControl itself.  Edited.

Comment: I just tried the latest code in your answer and it always displays at the very top of the screen, and it only move horizontally but not the right amount either.

Comment: The depth of the textbox is important, as you can gather from the edit.  Is tabControl1 on the form, or in another control such as a splitter or a panel?

Comment: tabControl1 is on the main form (Form1 > TabControl > SelectedTab > TextBox) - it's not in any container, just on the form.

Comment: What is "shortcuts" that you are trying to display?

Comment: shortcuts is a Form (a small form about 300px x 125px)

Comment: I really don't know whats wrong with me lately - not thinking properly!

Comment: Ugh the suspense...do tell!

Comment: Sorry about the delay, @Don, I was having connectivity issues as usual. I will place the code at the bottom of my question after writing this comment. Basically, I used the code you gave me and used a combination of TabControl.Location and MainMenu.Height, etc. I think it would be more easily explained by showing you the code. Thanks so much for your help!